# Url Routing/Rewriting in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

We want to add some more data tracking to our website and we want to attach a keyword onto the end of a url.

I have something like this

http://www.samplesite.com/t/1/video/123456

http://www.samplesite.com/t/2/video/123457

http://www.samplesite.com/t/3/video/123458

and I want it to look like this

http://www.samplesite.com/t/1/video/123456/funny

http://www.samplesite.com/t/2/video/123457/sports

http://www.samplesite.com/t/3/video/123458/informative

I've been searching the internet trying to figure out how to do this and I haven't really come up with anything. I'm able to paste those urls in and get to the right page but I don't actually know how to make those pages have those urls when they load. I realize this question is pretty open ended but I'm basically looking for some starting points on some more searches as I don't think I've been phrasing things the best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IIS 7 or 7.5 you can use the Microsoft URL Rewriter module, otherwise there are some third party ones for IIS6 and 5.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

There are several examples at: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-url-rewrite-module-20

So are you saying you go to one of those URLs and it shows what you expect, but the URL is changing (so it doesn't have the suffix)?

Comment: Yeah, somewhere during the process it is losing that end value that I want. I haven't been able to track it down yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [urlrewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/)?

A few references :

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.in/2008/07/url-rewriting-with-urlrewriternet.html

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/URL-Rewriting-in-ASP.NET-using-URLRewriter.Net/38861

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Hope this helps you.